# (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

Tags: 2010, development, error

I added a class library from one SharePoint solution to a console app. I wanted to isolate some xml mapping in class library so I could test it better without having to deploy my entire original SharePoint solution. After executing my console app, my SharePoint site collection now displays this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION)) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x80020009): Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ReleaseResources() +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ReleaseResources() +299

[SPException: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +117
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ReleaseResources() +446
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous) +3070
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode) +272
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny() +184
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRegionalSettings.get_GlobalInstalledLanguages() +27
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales() +63
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize() +72
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +949
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +480
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11318198
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4348404
```

The ULS Logs say:

```
08/07/2012 14:46:24.57  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x2744) 0x1748  SharePoint Foundation   General 837l    Exception   An unhandled exception occured. Watson will be invoked. 
08/07/2012 14:46:24.58  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x2744) 0x1748  SharePoint Foundation   Unified Logging Service c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", b9f3fc08 "owssvr.dll", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", 4db909d1 "wed apr 27 23:31:45 2011", MISSING, 000c65ff "000c65ff", c0000005 "c0000005", 3833376c "837l"   
08/07/2012 14:46:24.58  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x2744) 0x1748  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80020009  
08/07/2012 14:46:24.58  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x2744) 0x1748  SharePoint Foundation   General 837l    Exception   An unhandled exception occured. Watson will be invoked. 
08/07/2012 14:46:24.58  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x2744) 0x1748  SharePoint Foundation   Unified Logging Service c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", b9f3fc08 "owssvr.dll", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", 4db909d1 "wed apr 27 23:31:45 2011", MISSING, 0001ebf1 "0001ebf1", c0000005 "c0000005", 3833376c "837l"   
08/07/2012 14:46:24.58  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x2744) 0x1748  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80020009  
08/07/2012 14:46:24.90  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0938)    0x099C  SharePoint Foundation   Sandboxed Code Service  fe8d    Medium  -  - Error warming up the worker process. - Inner Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified.       Server stack trace:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcPort.Connect(String portName, Boolean secure, TokenImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel, Int32 timeout)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.ConnectionCache.GetConnection(String portName, Boolean secure, TokenImpersonationLevel level, Int32 timeout)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.IActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage msg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.LocalActivator.DoRemoteActivation(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.AppDomainLevelActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ClientContextTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.Activate(RemotingProxy remProxy, IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalActivate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(IMessage reqMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext_SubsetProxy..ctor()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)     at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.__CreateInstance_SPThreadContext(Boolean forStaticMethod, Object[] constructorParameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.FreeUserCodeCallContext__Inner()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.FreeUserCodeCallContext()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeThreadEnabler.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxyForShim.InitializeInternal(Int32 appDomainCount, Boolean alwaysRecycleAppDomains, Byte[] salt, Boolean logRequests)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy.Initialize(Int32 appDomainCount, Boolean alwaysRecycleAppDomains, Byte[] salt, Boolean logRequests)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.ISPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy.Initialize(Int32 appDomainCount, Boolean alwaysRecycleAppDomains, Byte[] salt, Boolean logRequests)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.InitializeWorkerProcess(ISPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy workerProcessProxy, Boolean alwaysRecycleAppDomains, Byte[] saltBytes, Boolean logRequests)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.InitializeWorkerProcesses()    
08/07/2012 14:46:24.90  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0938)    0x099C  SharePoint Foundation   Sandboxed Code Service  ei0t    Medium  - Process creation/initialization threw an exception. Stopping this process. "ipc://9031e612-e0d1-4a6a-95ec-f4f14490b831:7000"  
08/07/2012 14:46:24.90  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0938)    0x099C  SharePoint Foundation   Sandboxed Code Service  i0o2    Monitorable - Stopping shim process. Shim process name: "SPUCWorkerProcess" Shim PID: "0x09FC" Shim service url: "ipc://9031e612-e0d1-4a6a-95ec-f4f14490b831:7000"  
08/07/2012 14:46:24.92  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0938)    0x099C  SharePoint Foundation   Sandboxed Code Service  fe87    Medium  -  - Process has exited, so the requested information is not available. - Starting worker process threw
```

And PSConfig says:

```
08/07/2012 14:48:12  9  ERR                        Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ReleaseResources()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ReleaseResources()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ReleaseResources()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.InitUserToken(SPRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPSiteConstructor(SPFarm farm, Guid applicationId, Guid contentDatabaseId, Guid siteId, Guid siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone zone, Uri requestUri, String serverRelativeUrl, Boolean hostHeaderIsSiteName, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.get_Item(String strSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.get_HealthRules()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health.SPHealthAnalyzer.RegisterRules(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Util.HealthAnalyzerRegistration.RegisterHealthRules()
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Administration.FormsService.Update()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
```

What I've tried:

- Recycle App Pools
- IIS Reset
- Recycle Services Timer
- Restart server
- Start SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard which fails

Any other suggestions on what I should try?

Comment: What does the ULS logs and the PSConfigUI.exe errors say?

Comment: I added them in the original post.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong. What exactly does your console application?

Comment: Close to nothing. It opens an xml file in a XDoc and passes it to the class library. The strange thing is, this doesn't happen on a different SharePoint environment that I have.