# After system state restore: (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, exception, psconfig, small-business-server

So the system drive of our SBS 2011 server has crashed. We had a backup which we used to perform a systemstate recovery and non-authorative restore of Active Directory. Since the restore, our SharePoint Foundation 2010 is no longer working and all services fail with the same exception.

We cannot use the following services:

```
Companyweb
Central Administration
Sharepoint Management Shell
PSConfig (fails on step 2)
PSConfigUI
STADM
```

Our symptoms are exactly the same as in this question: [(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42838/exception-from-hresult-0x80020009-disp-e-exception)

Whenever we try to run PSConfig or open any sharepoint site, we get this dreaded exception:

```
[COMException (0x80020009): Er is een uitzondering opgetreden. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ReleaseResources() +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ReleaseResources() +284

[SPException: Er is een uitzondering opgetreden. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +28031154
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ReleaseResources() +28254608
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous) +28035897
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode) +268
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny() +173
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRegionalSettings.get_GlobalInstalledLanguages() +27
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales() +60
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize() +69
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +931
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +480
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382

[HttpException (0x80004005): Er is een uitzondering opgetreden. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11421094
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4405316
```

We tried to reconfigure Sharepoint, to Reinstall sharepoint. We tried various PSConfig and STASDM commands. Also we tried the solution posted here: http://itgroove.net/mmman/2015/04/29/how-to-resolve-failures-in-the-sharepoint-product-config-psconfig-tool/

This has proved unsuccesfully so far.

What do we need to do to get Sharepoint up and running again?